# Google User Messaging Platform (UMP) SDK in case I use both Ad Manager and AdMob

Tags: admob, google-ad-manager, cmp, ump

Beginning January 16, 2024, publishers and developers using Google AdSense, Ad Manager, or AdMob will be required to use a Consent Management Platform (CMP) that has been certified by Google and has integrated with the IAB's Transparency and Consent Framework (TCF) when serving ads to users in the European Economic Area or the UK.

Google offers app publishers the User Messaging Platform (UMP) SDK. Learn more about adding the Google User Messaging Platform (UMP) SDK to your apps (Ad Manager, AdMob) and creating a GDPR message for apps (Ad Manager, AdMob).

My apps are delivering audio ads through Ad Manager and banner ads through AdMob, I am wondering if I need to incorporate the UMP SDK for both platforms and set up GDPR messages on each.

Could it potentially lead to my app's users receiving two separate messages?